# How to properly trigger SQLite database operations in AsyncTask based on user behavior in other Activities

Tags: android, sqlite, android-asynctask, static-methods, static-variables

I have a separate class file that extends Asynctask (instead of an inner class) and I need it to perform different database operations depending on what the user does (clicks, swipes) in other Activities. Although my code works as desired, I don’t know if using static methods and static boolean flags is the generally accepted way to trigger the proper database operations. Is there another approach that I am missing, a design pattern perhaps? This is a very simplified version of my code for illustration.

**FirstActivity.java**

```
public class FirstActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static boolean wasSwiped = false;

    …  // other code

    // to detect swipes
    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2,
                           float velocityX, float velocityY) {

    if( // swipe was determined) {
        wasSwiped = true;
        new UpdateDatabaseTask().execute();
    }

    public static boolean getWasSwiped() {
        return wasSwiped;
    }

    public static void setWasSwiped(boolean b) {
        wasSwiped = b;
    }
}
```

**SecondActivity.java**

```
public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static boolean wasTapped = false;

    …  // other code

    // to detect taps
    @Override
     public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
        wasTapped = true;
        new UpdateDatabaseTask().execute();

    }

    public static boolean getWasTapped() {
        return wasTapped;
    }

    public static void setWasTapped(boolean b) {
        wasTapped = b;
    }
}
```

**UpdateDatabaseTask.java**

```
public class UpdateDatabaseTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Object… objectArray) {

        ...  // code to initialize database

        if(FirstActivity.getWasSwiped() {
            // do something with database
            FirstActivity.setWasSwiped(false);
        }

        if(SecondActivity.getWasTapped() {
            // do something different with database
            SecondActivity.setWasTapped(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: AFAIK, `AsyncTask` is scheduled to be deprecated in the next version of Android. It is 2020; IMHO nobody should be using `AsyncTask` for new development. And, as you suspected, your approach for using `static` fields here is not good. Up-to-date educational materials on Android app development will show you better approaches: threads managed by `LiveData`, `ViewModel`, the repository pattern with dependency inversion, fragments instead of multiple activities, etc.

Comment: @CommonsWare I appreciate your input and I will definitely look into each of your suggestions for current approaches to my project. However, for educational purposes, what could you recommend as a proper communication method (instead of getters and setters)  between activities and an AsyncTask? (Let's assume AsyncTask wasn't deprecated). I feel like it will help me and others reading this post to write code that isn't "hacky" as I originally did.

Comment: The "best of breed" approach for `AsyncTask` was to use a retained fragment as the container for the `AsyncTask`, as a retained fragment survives configuration changes. Your `AsyncTask`, through the fragment, can find out what activity instance (if any) owns the fragment. From there, it would be a matter of casting that activity instance to an appropriate type (e.g., an interface) and calling a method to tell the activity that such-and-so happened. This is complex and still leaves a bunch of places for problems (e.g., task completes after activity is destroyed).